# How to make commented out html a different color in Vim?

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am very new to Vim.

In other text editors, like Notepad++ and Sublime, when html is commented out, it becomes a different color. Is there a setting or command in Vim that can do this?

```
<div>Normal color</div>
<!--<div>This would be a different color</div>-->
<div>Normal color</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing a new file and haven't saved it yet, enable the syntax highlighting and set the file type to `html`:

```
:syntax on
:set ft=html
```

File type is detected automatically when you save a file. Syntax highlighting however is disabled by default, so you may want to add this this to your `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. I didn't realize it at first, but my file is a .jsp, not .html. So, setting ft=html works great, but when I open the file, since it is not html, I have to set ft=html to make the comments look right. Is there a way to change my vimrc so that it automatically sets .jsp files to be .html files?

Comment: There is. Add to `.vimrc` `au BufEnter *.jsp set ft=html`